# How to implement a copy constructor for a singly linked list utilizing smart pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor, smart-pointers, deque

This is the first time I'm actually posting a question here! I was having some trouble creating a copy constructor for a singly linked list. I have searched high and low for a comparable example on this and various other sites to no avail. I was trying to use smart pointers and so far have only used `unique_ptr(s)`. This function is meant to make a deep copy of the linked list it's being passed. I have tried the following so far but I only get a segfault. I've run some tests and I believe my `insert_front()` and `insert_back()` functions are working fine. I do have pointers to both the head and the tail if that helps. The following is the code I've tried.

```
Deque::Deque(const Deque& deque2copy){
    this -> head = 0;
    unique_ptr<Node> temp = make_unique<Node>(deque2copy.head -> val, move(deque2copy.head->next));
    while(temp != 0){
        this ->insert_back(temp->val);
        temp = move(temp-> next);
    }
}
```

UPDATE #1

```
Deque::Deque(const Deque& deque2copy){

    if(deque2copy.head->next == nullptr){
        return;
    } else {
       this -> head = 0;
       unique_ptr<Node> temp = make_unique<Node>(*deque2copy.head->next);
       while(temp != 0){
            this ->insert_back(temp->val);
            temp = move(temp-> next);
       } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you moving from the container being copied? That's `auto_ptr` non-intuitive

Comment: without the `move()` it didn't' seem to compile. I thought it was needed to allow copying a `unique_ptr` ?

Comment: Move enables moving from it. If you move, you don't get the original anymore.  I think you may have wanted `make_unique<Node>(*deque2copy.head->next)`

Comment: I now get a seg fault as soon as the copy constructor is called :/

Comment: Ah, then only construct a copy if the pointer `deque2copy.head->next` is non-null

Comment: That seems to at least allow the copy constructor to run, thank you! Ive attached the revised function, however, I think that the body of my while loop isn't correctly copying the data over. When I try to `peek_front()` at the front of the copied list my code throws a `runtime_error` (as I designed it to). However the function works for the original list.

Comment: Why does it throw a `runetime_error`? The exception type isn't descriptive as to the logic you use to decide when to throw it.

Comment: By the way, on an attempt to copy an empty list: `if(deque2copy.head->next == nullptr)` will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post much information on how your `Deque` or `Node` classes actually look like exactly. Based on the information glanced from your code snippets your main problem is that you use `std::unique_ptr<T>` to navigate your list: that won't work: whenever a non-null `std::unique_ptr<T>` is assigned or destroyed it will release the held object. You'll need a non-owning pointer.

Since you didn't post much context information I couldn't easily test whether this code works but I'd assume it should be fine:

```
Deque::Deque(const Deque& deque2copy)
    : head() { // the default constructor does the null-initialization
    std::unique_ptr<Node>* tail(&this->head);
    for (Node* temp(deque2copy.head.get()); temp; temp = temp->next.get()) {
        *tail = std::make_unique<Node>(temp->value);
        tail = &tail->next;
    }
}
```

Note that this code navigates the two lists using non-owning pointers:

- for the source list it uses `Node*` obtained from `std::unique_ptr<Node>::get()` to avoid destroying the `Node` object when assigning or destroying a `std::unique_ptr<Node>`.
- for the destination list a pointer `tail` to the current last `std::unique_ptr<Node>` in the list (initially `head` and once this is assigned the last `next` pointer in the list) is kept to efficiently append a node.

The code does assume that `Node` has a constructor taking `value` as constructor argument. This constructor would initialize the the `value` member accordingly and default initialize the `next` member, e.g.:

```
Node::Node(T const& value)
    : value(value)
    , next() {
}
```

Please be aware that using owning pointers for the elements of a list is generally a bad idea: the destructor of head will recursively call the destructors of all nodes in the list. Depending on how the destructor is actually written this recursion may easily create a stack overflow. To combat that you'll need to write a custom destructor for your list to avoid this recursion. However, doing so entirely defeats the purpose of using `std::unique_ptr`s to maintain the nodes to start with.